# How to copy Redux store in component state with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm making live search component

I'm getting posts from Redux

```
const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts);
```

Than I create postsFiltered array in component state

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    postsFiltered: []
  })
```

Action to get data from backend in order them to appear in redux. When they appear (2) I copy posts to component state

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(showPosts())

    setState(state => ({ ...state, postsFiltered: posts })); ///(2)
  }, [dispatch]); (3)
```

Next I show this list:

```
return (
       state.postsFiltered.map(post => {
              return (
                     {post.name}
              )
       })
)
```

Problem is that posts from Redux doesn't appear in component state. I see that state in Redux is updated three times (there are also two actions on the same page).

Also React wants me to add posts in array of dependencies of useEffect (3), but when I add it applications starts to update infinite times.

How to get data from Redux to component state correctly?

Here is also function how I filter search results

```
const onSearch = (e) => {
    const postsFiltered = posts.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()))
    setState(state => ({ ...state, postsFiltered }))
  }
```

Search input works with onChange:

```
<Search
          placeholder="input search text"
          onChange={onSearch}
        />
```

Comment: Why not just do `const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts.filter(....));
 `

Comment: I'm not getting how to make it inside onSearch function. I need to make it live (when I type code inside search input it should be changed in the list). Updated my question

Comment: Then put the search in state: `const [searchState,setSearhState] = useState(); onChange={setSearchState}` and in the selector you check if search isn't empty

Answer (score 0):

You have to use useSelect for posts, useState for search string from input and useMemo for filteredPosts.

```
const posts = useSelect(state => state.posts);
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
const filtered = useMemo(() => posts.filter(({name}) => name.toLowerCase().includes(search), [search, posts]);
```